# Can a pointer to a memory be used as initialized trivial type?

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

Is it undefined behavior to use a trivial type without initialization?

```
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*100);
void* num_mem = mem + sizeof(uint64_t)*31;
//does the lifetime of uint64_t starts here:
uint64_t* mynum = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(num_mem); //?
*mynum = 5; //is it UB?
std::cout << *mynum << std::endl; //is it UB?
free(mem);
```

I found out that calling of a destructor of trivial/POD/aggregate types is not necessary, but can't find the same for beginning of a lifetime of trivial/POD/aggregate type. Did I have to call `new(num_mem) uint64_t;` instead of `reinterpret_cast ..`?

Does the behavior changes if it's a POD or aggregate object, without constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the following is following the rules of C++20, although the implicit object creation is considered a defect report against earlier versions as well. Before C++17 the meaning of pointer values was very different and so the discussion in the answer and the comments might not apply. All of this is also strictly about what the standard guarantees. Of course compilers may allow more in practice.

---

Yes, if the type and all of the types of its subobjects are [*implicit-lifetime types*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType), which is a weaker requirement than being trivial or POD. It does apply to aggregate types, but not necessarily to the subobjects of the aggregate type, in which case these still need to be explicitly `new`ed (e.g. consider the member of `struct A { std::string s; };`).

You also need to assure that the size and alignment of the memory are suitable. `std::malloc` returns memory aligned at least as strict as `std::max_align_t`, so it is good for any scalar type, but not for overaligned types.

Also, `std::malloc` is one of a few functions that is specifically specified to implicitly create objects and return a pointer to one. It does not generally work for arbitrary memory. For example if you use the memory location as `uint64_t`, then the implicitly created object is `uint64_t`. Cast afterwards to a different type will cause an aliasing violation.

The details are rather complicated and are easy to get wrong. It is much safer to explicitly create objects with `new` (which doesn't require initialization to a value either) and then use the pointer returned by `new` to access the object.

Also `mem + sizeof(uint64_t)*31` is a GNU extension. It is not possible to perform pointer arithmetic on `void*` pointers in standard C++. You need to cast to the element type first and then perform the arithemtic, assuming that you only store the same types in the memory. Otherwise it gets a bit more complicated.

(Also, you are missing a null pointer check for the return value of `malloc`.)

Comment: interesting, so its a well-defined code, until I care about alignment.
I specifically created 800 bytes buffer to avoid any specialization to a type.

Comment: regarding the pointer arithmetics, I assume having a pointer to a char would do the trick?

Comment: @Arkady Alignment is always relevant since unaligned objects cannot exist in standard C++ at all (or at least they can never have their lifetime started). You cannot reuse the memory for different types at the same location without intervening `new` or some other function that is specified to implicitly create objects (e.g. `memcpy`).

Comment: @Arkady Yes, or better `unsigned char` (there is a minor defect in the standard with regards to `char`). However this will imply that the implicit object creation will create an array of `(unsigned) char` in the storage and then create an object of the target type _nested_ in this array. The pointer returned from `malloc` then points to the `char` element, not the nested object. Consequently you will need to `std::launder` the pointer after the cast in that case. In any case it doesn't change what I said above: Reusing the same memory location for multiple types will still result in UB.

Comment: if I got you correctly, as only I interpret memory returning from std::malloc as an implicit-lifetime type -- it is the beginning of its lifetime. And the lifetime will safely end at the moment of freeing the memory. But as only I reintepret memory behind such object as an object of a different type -- it is UB.

Comment: is there an article to read about the subject regarding C++11?

Comment: @Arkady Lifetime ends when the (pseudo-)destructor is called, the memory is deallocated or reused for another object. That is true for all types (at least since C++20). Yes the whole idea is just that `malloc` may do the analogue of an implicit `new` for some types. Trying to reinterpret this implicit object as another type is an aliasing violation under the same rules as it would be for an explicitly `new`ed object.

Comment: @Arkady Before C++20 there was nothing in the standard allowing implicit object creation at all (but that was fixed as a defect report). Before C++17 pointer values were determined by their address, not the specific object they point to, and I think as a result a lot of these things weren't really well specified. I can link you the paper introducing the changes if I find it.

Comment: @Arkady Seems there wasn't really a paper explaining the C++17 change. There is only a wording paper (https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0137r1.html). I suppose the change was made because it simply was inconsistent beforehand. But the paper regarding implicit object creation is this one: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html